# Unable to pass props to makeStyles when using material UI with next.js

Tags: material-ui, next.js

I am using Next.js with material UI.

I have created a  Icon and when clicked it calls the setOpenFn() and sets the open variable to be true. This variable is then passed as props to the useStyles(). Now I display the search bar if open is true. But I get the below error

```
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "makeStyles-search-3 makeStyles-search-8" Client: "makeStyles-search-3 makeStyles-search-9"
```

When the search Icon is clicked display: flex property is also not working.

I tried to create .babelrc file and added this

```json
{
    "presets": ["next/babel"],
    "plugins": [["styled-components", { "ssr": true }]]
  }
```

but still nothing works.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({

search: {

[theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      display: (props) => (props.open ? 'flex' : 'none'),
      width: '70%',
    },

}
  
}))

const Navbar = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const setOpenFn = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const classes = useStyles({ open });

  return(
   <Search
            className={classes.searchButton}
            onClick={() => {
              setOpenFn();
            }}
          />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using mui version 5+

According to [this migration guide](https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/v5-style-changes/#%E2%9C%85-adjust-css-injection-order)! you need to wrap your JSX with the following component.

```
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>

    </StyledEngineProvider>
```